# How to implement custom shape tab bar indicator in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tabs, tabbar

I want to build custom shape indicator I know it can be achieved using canvas widget to draw custom shape but i am unable to do if you can give some hint or share some code to achieved this UI. it would be very helpful .
Thanks !!.

[image: Shape of indicator]

Comment: I think it's not possible with the tab bar indicator directly. You'll probably want to use `CustomPainter` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a trick i ask designer to provide svg file of the indicator .
Then i go to [fluttershapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/)and upload svg file and it give me custom paint and code and boy oh boy it works perfectly.

Here is custom paint code generated by [fluttershapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/)

```
class TabPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color? color;

  TabPainter({this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint0Fill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint0Fill.color = const Color(0xff9AE9E1).withOpacity(1.0);

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.08426966, size.height * 0.2744795);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.08426966,
        size.height * 0.03409159,
        size.width * 0.02544281,
        size.height * 0.001752948,
        0,
        size.height * 0.001753373);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9438202, size.height * 0.001753373);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.9748483,
        size.height * 0.001753373,
        size.width,
        size.height * 0.1035068,
        size.width,
        size.height * 0.2290250);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.9790273);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width,
        size.height * 0.8863636,
        size.width * 0.9765899,
        size.height * 0.8653909,
        size.width * 0.9662921,
        size.height * 0.8653909);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1460674, size.height * 0.8653909);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.1095506,
        size.height * 0.8653909,
        size.width * 0.08426966,
        size.height * 0.7727273,
        size.width * 0.08426966,
        size.height * 0.5926636);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.08426966, size.height * 0.2744795);
    path_0.close();

    paint0Fill.color = const Color(0xff9AE9E1).withOpacity(1.0);
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint0Fill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```